# Cannot compile BeeTee framework because of missing BluetoothDevice.h file

Tags: ios, compiler-errors

I followed all the step mentioned here BeeTee https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee. I went through other pages as well. Unable to add BluetoothManager.framework as a private framework in my local system.
Note that I am developing testing tool, which I am not planning to push Apple store.
Environment details: Xcode : 5.1, iOS SDK 7.1
I download BeeTee code and try to build, getting an error "Lexical or Preprocessor issue 'BluetoothManager/BluetoothDevice.h' file not found.

How can I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgot to put the whole headers folder into the framework folder?

It should look like

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/Headers/
```

and then containing all header files. Or as screenshot

[image: Folder structure for private framework BluetoothManager]

If you are now using iOS 8 or later you can also try to run [the bash script](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee/blob/master/checkheaders.sh) to check if you put the headers correctly.

Comment: Just placing headers in the "System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/Headers/" folder was not solving me. I had to add header folders in the xcode project, which solved all my problems. This solution is not working for iOS8.

Comment: Then you do something wrong, because I am running `BeeTee` just one minute ago on an iPhone 5s with iOS 8.0.2. 
Please read the instructions more carefully: It is not the path what you mentioned above, it is in the Xcode-App folder!

Comment: Another ideas are restarting Xcode and removing the BluetoothManager.framework and then adding it again.